# How to safely push previous commits without losing the ones that are ahead

Tags: git

Let's say I have multiple commits (newer to older):

- 3xc1849 - Added advanced search functionality. **(This is the HEAD BTW)**
- 4cc9886 - Added function to compute role policies, minor bug fixes introduced by migrating to RolesAPI.
- 162f27e - Switched to Permissions Manager v2.0.

1. I want to push `4cc9886` and `162f27e` to my remote repository without losing progress made on `3xc1849`.
2. Eventually push `3xc1849`.

Comment: looks like you want to reorder commits. you can try interactive rebasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

There's nothing special to do.  Just use `git push` as shown below.

#### Long

Each commit:

- is numbered: these are the strings you mention here (though these are abbreviated, and one of them is not actually possible: `3xc1849` is not a valid number);
- contains the commit number—the hash ID—of the *previous* commit, as part of its metadata.

What this means is that given a linear series of commits, if we use uppercase letters to stand in for the actual hash IDs, we can draw them like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Git finds the *last* commit in the sequence using a branch name, which holds the actual hash ID (whatever number `H` stands in for here).  Commit `H` itself holds the hash ID of earlier commit `G`, so by reading `H`, Git can find `G`.  `G` in turn holds the hash ID of earlier commit `F`, and so on.

When you use `git push`, your Git will send, to the other Git, any commits that they need, but do not yet have, based on the commit number you ask your Git to send.  That is, you start by saying to your Git: *Please send to the other Git, commit `G`* (you fill in the hash ID).  *When it gets there, ask them to set their branch name `B`* (you fill in the name).

The *way* you say this is with:

```
git push name-of-other-git hash-ID-of-G:B
```

If you use:

```
git push name-of-other-git B
```

you're telling your Git to use the hash ID found by turning *your* name `B` into a hash ID, and then your Git should *repeat that name* to *their* Git.  So the short-hand version sends *all* commits, then syncs up the names.  The long version, however, lets you choose how many commits to send.

Once `git push` actually gets started and has called up the Git at the URL stored under your name *`name-of-other-git`*, your Git hands the hash ID over to their Git.  They either say: *Aha, I have that one already* or *I don't have that one, please send it*.  If they say *please send it*, your Git is now *obligated* to offer that commit's parent.  In this case, because we are having our Git send them commit `G`, our Git must now offer commit `F`.  They look in their big database of all the commits they have, to see if they have that hash ID.  If so, they say *ah, I have that one already*, and if not, they say *please send that too* and we must go on to offer `F`'s parent.

Eventually, we meet up at a commit they already have, or send every commit from `G` backwards and there are no more to send.  Now that all commits have made it there, we have our Git ask their Git to set *their* branch *`B`*, and they either say *OK, done* or *I can't because _____* (they fill in this blank).  Your Git now reports success or failure to you.

Comment: lol I added the invalid commit to make it a bit clearer, it backfired! So would an actual command look like `git push nameOfMyRemoteRepo 162f27e master`?

Comment: No, but close: there's an explicit colon in between the hash ID and the other-Git-branch-name: `git push origin 162f27e:master` for instance. (I think from your question you actually wanted to send 4cc9886, which includes 162f27e, not *just* 162f27e, but it's safe to send one, then send the next. It's just less efficient than sending the later one which drags the earlier one with it.)

Answer (score 1):

That would be :

```
# replace <branch_name> with the name of the branch you wish to update
# on your remote :
git push origin 4cc9886:<branch_name>
```

You will still have your local `3xc1849` commit, on top of `4cc9886`.